# AWS SNS Confirm Sub

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to implement push notification on my site with AWS SNS https protocol but am having trouble figuring out how to receive the token returned from the subscribe method. What is an example of a handler that processes the confirm sub POST request from SNS? I'm currently proving the browser's endpoint as the param to subscribe, is that the right endpoint? I've gone through the SNS Doc multiple times but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

this is the response i'm getting from the subscribe method:

`{ ResponseMetadata: {…}, SubscriptionArn: "pending confirmation" }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read the HTTP headers of the HTTP POST requests that Amazon SNS sends to your endpoint. Please see [Source] for the HTTP header example.

Read the value for SubscribeURL and visit that URL. To confirm the subscription and start receiving notifications at the endpoint, you must visit the SubscribeURL by HTTP Get request.

```
  if (message['Type'] === 'SubscriptionConfirmation') {
        https.get(message['SubscribeURL'], function (res) {
          // You have confirmed your endpoint subscription
        });
    }
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html#SendMessageToHttp.confirm

Comment: Can you share an example on how I can handle this POST request after calling the subscribe method?

Comment: updated a sample code, you need to get the SubscribeURL and do a HTTP get.

Comment: Thanks for the sample! Is message the return value from sns.subscribe? this is the endpoint i'm using https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABamEal7... is this what I should be using?

Comment: When you subscribe an HTTP endpoint, Amazon SNS sends it a subscription confirmation request or you can also use ConfirmSubscription.

Comment: My question is, how would I listen to this to this request? My subscription flow goes like this: Button clicked => ask permission => allow => call sns subscribe with the endpoint.

Comment: https://github.com/deepstreamIO/dsh-demo-sns-integration/blob/master/sns-provider.js#L24-L28

Comment: @ShawnYap the confirmation token is sent in a message *to the endpoint*.  If you subscribe an HTTPS endpoint to an SNS topic, SNS wants *that endpoint* to confirm -- not you.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I know that. I just had to confirm. Thanks